# PHP class not setting one of my variables

Tags: php, oop

I have a class that I use to display pages, and I set many class wide variables in the constructor. One of them is coming up null, even though I can see in the call to create the object that the argument is passed. Here is the constructor for the class:

```
public function __contruct(string $pageTitle, string $page, bool $csrfFlag, string $pageType) {
    $this->pageTitle = $pageTitle;
    $this->page = $page;
    $this->csrfFlag = $csrfFlag;

    // Validating page type passed
    switch ($pageType) {
        case "main":
        case "profile":
        case "admin":
            $this->pageType = $pageType;
        default:
            throw new Exception("A page type variable was passed that is unknown. That variable was $pageType");
    }

}
```

And here is the particular object creation call:

```
$display = new PageDisplay('Login', 'login.php', true, 'auth_page');
```

The problem I'm having is that the variable marked $page isn't being passed through (and I know that because I try and call a late function in the class that displays pages and when it comes to the line about displaying the actual page (in this case, login.php) it gives me this error:
`Failed opening '' for inclusion`).
 Here is that function if you would like to see it:

```
// Ultimately builds the page to show the user
public function buildPage(bool $needsHeadTags) : void {

    // Generate CSRF token if needed
    if ($this->csrfFlag === true) { $csrfToken = hash("sha512", random_bytes(64)); }

    // Get extra HTML
    if ($needsHeadTags === true) { $extraHeadTags = $this->getHeadTags(); }
    $headerHtml = $this->getHeader();
    $pageTitle = $this->pageTitle;

    // Show page
    include_once $this->page; // where the error is thrown

}
```

But I can see that it is passed in the constructor. **What am I doing wrong?**

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

class PageDisplay {

    private $simplePageNav = true;
    private $header = "";
    private $pageTitle;
    private $page;
    private $csrfFlag;
    private $pageType;

    // Sets the variables the rest of the class will use
    public function __contruct(string $pageTitle, string $page, bool $csrfFlag, string $pageType) {
        $this->pageTitle = $pageTitle;
        $this->page = $page;
        $this->csrfFlag = $csrfFlag;

        // Validating page type passed
        switch ($pageType) {
            case "main":
            case "profile":
            case "admin":
                $this->pageType = $pageType;
            default:
                throw new Exception("A page type variable was passed that is unknown. That variable was $pageType");
        }

    }

    public function getPage() : string {
        return $this->page;
    }

    // If the function returns true, it is just a simple navigation to the page
    public static function isPageNav(bool $getAllowed) : bool {

        // Checking if GET parameters are allowed, then checking if the correct things are empty, then return boolean with what we find
        if (!$getAllowed) {
            $simplePageNav = (empty($_POST) && empty($_GET) && empty(file_get_contents("php://input"))) ? true : false;
        } else {
            $simplePageNav = (empty($_POST) && empty(file_get_contents("php://input"))) ? true : false;
        }

        return $simplePageNav;

    }

    // Gets what the navigation should be based on what type of page the user went to (general web, profile, admin, etc...)
    private function getHeader() : string {

        // Control statement to display website correctly
        switch($this->pageType) {
            case "auth_page":
                return "";
            break;
        }

        return "hard";

    }

    // Gets what the additional head tags should be based on what type of page the user went to (general web, profile, admin, etc...)
    private function getHeadTags() : string {

        // Control statement to display website correctly
        switch($this->pageType) {
            //

        }

    }

    // Ultimately builds the page to show the user
    public function buildPage(bool $needsHeadTags) : void {

        // Generate CSRF token if needed
        if ($this->csrfFlag === true) { $csrfToken = hash("sha512", random_bytes(64)); }

        // Get extra HTML
        if ($needsHeadTags === true) { $extraHeadTags = $this->getHeadTags(); }
        $headerHtml = $this->getHeader();
        $pageTitle = $this->pageTitle;

        // Show page
        include_once $this->page;

    }


}
```

Comment: Have you put in debugging code to check the value of `$display->page` after object initialisation and at various points in the object's life cycle? Are there other object functions that affect `page`?

Comment: @ialarmedalien no, there is nothing else except this code that affects page and when I try and echo it out through a getter, null is returned

Comment: Is it definitely getting set on object initialisation?

Comment: @ialarmedalien I mean, that code is getting called, I don't know how else you would tell if it were definitely getting set

Comment: @ialarmedalien done

Comment: Check the spelling of `construct` -- doh! :)

Comment: @ialarmedalien Gosh dang it!! Thanks...that's twice I've done something like that now!!! If you put it as an answer I'd be happy to give it to you!

Comment: Thanks! I've tried to make the answer a little educational. ;)  I'm glad to have been able to help - I was starting to think I was going crazy trying to work out the problem. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has a number of "special" methods that can be added to classes that get automatically called at points during the class lifecycle. The `__construct` function is executed on object initialisation, and `__destruct` on object destruction, when there are no remaining references to the object or when the script or program ends. It's totally legal to create other class functions that also start with a double underscore, so PHP will not complain about this:

```
class PageDisplay {

    // Sets the variables the rest of the class will use
    public function __contruct(string $pageTitle, string $page, bool $csrfFlag, string $pageType) {
        // code not executed unless $object->__contruct is called
    }
}
```

but the code in the `__contruct` function will not be executed when a new `PageDisplay` object is created.

The fix is simple:

```
class PageDisplay {

    // Sets the variables the rest of the class will use
    public function __construct(string $pageTitle, string $page, bool $csrfFlag, string $pageType) {
        // code executed on calling new PageDisplay('...')
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to make it painfully clear for the next reader, `__contruct` is spelt wrong.